# Set Facebook AppId and AppSecret programmatically?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I've recently upgraded from v5 of the facebook c# sdk to v6 and am wondering what to do with this code:

```
Facebook.FacebookApplication.SetApplication(new Facebook.DefaultFacebookApplication()
{
     AppId = "AppId",
     AppSecret = "appSecret"
});
```

I read the docs and saw how the AppId/AppSecret were set in web.config, but that doesn't work for me because the AppId/AppSecret can vary based on who is viewing the page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I used app.config for reading appid/secret. Can You provide why do You need to know who is viewing the page ? Because for application appid and secret are static values.

Comment: @oleh I need to set them dynamically because the user is the one providing the AppId/AppSecret.

Comment: I cant understand Your problem. For example if user insert appid/secret in some text field ar block , just read and set them to Your fields.